# How to use Parameters ind d3.selectAll('line').each

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to create an array with all endpoints of all lines in my SVG.

For this, I thought to iterate over all lines with d3-each.

Now for understanding, what do the Parameters of this function contain?

```
d3.select('svgEditor').selectAll('line').each(function(d,i){});
```

I know that `i` is the index but `d`, in this case, is always empty.

Shouldn't there be some Kind of iterated element or data inside?
And is iterating the correct way or is it simpler and faster possible, perhaps with some function like a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to access your lines is d3.select(this) inside the function. The d parameter is the joined datum. I don't know if there is a better way to iterate, but the .each function works out for me.

Here is the example usage of .each from https://www.d3indepth.com/selections/ :

```
    function addNumberedCircle(d, i) {
    d3.select(this)
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', 40);

      d3.select(this)
        .append('text')
        .text(i + 1)
        .attr('y', 50)
        .attr('x', 30);
    }

    d3.selectAll('g.item')
      .each(addNumberedCircle);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I Need to use d3.select(this) but I was wondering what Parameters should be in there. Or is it always, at every JavaScript-function the same and sometimes it contains data, sometimes not?

Comment: First, No, javascript functions can have as many parameter as needed. Second, your d shouldn't be empty. You can access the properties of your data d. If this doesn't work then something is going wrong. Usually you should be able to use your data d like this:                                            parent.each(function(p, j) {
  d3.select(this)
    .selectAll(".child")
      .text(d => `child ${d.name} of ${p.name}`);
});

Comment: And if you don't need the parameters, you can actually put in a function without parameters as well, since javascript is able to handle it.

Comment: ok, perhaps empty wasn't the Right Definition. If I log d, I get undefined in the console. So I asked myself, if I Need the index, do I Always have to set these both Parameters? I think for the function it is no difference if I Name the index i or ind or index or whatever, so the function has to know, that the second Parameter is the index? Is this Right?

Comment: yes the function always knows the second parameter is the index.. whatever you may call it - could you vote my answer up.. I have no reputation yet and I can't answer any questions anymore -.-

Comment: But it isn't right that your d is undefined as well. Can it be that you are accessing a wrond parameter of d. And the parameter is undefined? d only should be undefined if the elements in your selection are undefined...

Comment: No, i directly logged d to console `console.log(d)` and I think this should be anything but undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says that the three parameters for the .each function are (1) the data, (2) the current index, and (3) the nodes in the selection. https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.1/README.md#selection_each

Putting an answer here just in case anyone would like to use an ES6 arrow function, or they are running into issues using the 'this' keyword that was used in the accepted answer.

Using 'this' is fine when selecting elements in an each function, but I have gotten into problems using 'this' in SPA applications, where often 'this' means something else and it can get confusing.

To avoid using 'this' the code can be changed from:

```
d3.select('svgEditor').selectAll('line').each(function(d,i){
  d3.select(this).append.....
});
```

To:

```
d3.select('svgEditor').selectAll('line').each((data, i, nodes) => {
  d3.select(nodes[i]).append....
});
```

This article was helpful in explaining https://medium.com/@yonester/on-d3-and-arrow-functions-b6559c1cebb8